# Excel to tsv automatic updation

Tags: excel, csv

Is there any scrips or tooling that could convert all the excel changes / editions dynamically into the tsv file ? My requirement is to make the changes done in the excel sheet to get reflected on to the tsv file of the same dynamically, the moment we save the excel sheet, its tsv should be  edited and should contained the modification.

Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score 0):

This VBA macro is based on work over at [Mr. Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/428746-workbook-after-save-event.html) but extended to save in two formats at once.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

' break the save
Cancel = True

' perform the save wourself
Application.EnableEvents = False
Me.SaveAs Filename:="c:\tmp\x.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.EnableEvents = True

' do something after the save

Me.SaveAs Filename:="c:\tmp\x.tsv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCurrentPlatformText, CreateBackup:=False    
MsgBox "Workbook is saved in xlsm and tsv"    

End Sub
```